# How to modify the start and end hour in the day and week view?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Is it possible to modify the start and end hour in the day and week view ?

at present it starts at 12:00AM and ends at 11:00Pm.

is it possible to change the start hour and end hour in the parameters?

for example starting at 08:00 AM and ending at 18:00 PM
it would save some height in my case and show a schedule for working hours.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `agendaDay` and `agendaWeek` views instead of the `basicDay` and `basicWeek`. In the agenda views you can set your start-time using the `firstTime` option. Also, you can control what timeslots are visible using the `minTime` and `maxTime` options.

Take a look at the agendaOptions on the [FullCalendar documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/agenda/) - it explains this in detail!